# DataSourceID ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Greetings i have this Gridview, ASP.NET has a Wizard to bind Data to Gridview, it gives you the TSQL query in an asp.net tag, but i was wondering how to do it in C# in code-behind.

HTML:

```
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSourceMain" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Laptop %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [fCodeProducts], 
        [fCodeGroup], [fName], [fPrice], [fImageName],
        [fDesc], [fMojoodi], [Namayesh], 
        [FileAddress] FROM tProducts WHERE (fCodeGroup = 12) 
        OR (fCodeGroup = @fCodeGroup) AND (Namayesh = 'True') 
        ORDER BY fCodeGroup">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="GridView1" DefaultValue="200" Name="fCodeGroup" PropertyName="SelectedValue"
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change the SqlDataSource on code behind, you can do it like this:

```
SqlDataSourceMain.SelectCommand = "Select * from tProducts where Id=@MyParameter";
SqlDataSourceMain.SelectParameters["MyParameter"].DefaultValue = 1;
SqlDataSourceMain.DataBind();
```

You use it the exact same way, just bind it and bind it to your control.

Here is an [**Example**](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Bind-GridView-using-SqlDataSource-Programmatically-from-code-in-ASPNet.aspx) that goes into more depth.